# What does the Converter in C# Do?

Tags: c#

I was digging MSDN and found out this thing

```
public delegate TOutput Converter<in TInput, out TOutput>(
    TInput input
)
```

How do I use it? When should I use it? Is there any real world example for this?

**Edit**:

MSDN did tell me that List.ConvertAll utilized this. I want another example despite that.

Comment: Doesn't MSDN give an example?

Comment: I think you missed to scroll down.. there was an example as well...

Comment: [`List<T>.ConvertAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's a generic delegate that transforms a value of type `TInput` to a value of type `TOutput`. Pretty much every *Binding Converter* (`IValueConverter`) could implement a method based on that delegate.

Comment: Well, the reference source turns up [another few examples](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,39a21c9cc539e88d,references) of other places it's used within the framework. It's difficult to know what's going to satisfy *you* though.

Comment: see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Well, here is the example [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y(v=vs.110).aspx) itself gives:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create an array of PointF objects.
        PointF[] apf = {
            new PointF(27.8F, 32.62F),
            new PointF(99.3F, 147.273F),
            new PointF(7.5F, 1412.2F) };

        // Display each element in the PointF array.
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach( PointF p in apf )
            Console.WriteLine(p);

        // Convert each PointF element to a Point object.
        Point[] ap = Array.ConvertAll(apf, 
            new Converter<PointF, Point>(PointFToPoint));

        // Display each element in the Point array.
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach( Point p in ap )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
    }

    public static Point PointFToPoint(PointF pf)
    {
        return new Point(((int) pf.X), ((int) pf.Y));
    }
}

/* This code example produces the following output:

{X=27.8, Y=32.62}
{X=99.3, Y=147.273}
{X=7.5, Y=1412.2}

{X=27,Y=32}
{X=99,Y=147}
{X=7,Y=1412}
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple usage:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();

List<string> strings = ints.ConvertAll(x => x.ToString());
```

I think this was introduced before `Func<T1, TResult>` and Linq Extension Methods.

Answer (score 0):

IMO [`Converter<TInput, TOutput>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Predicate<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Comparison<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx) are obsolete delegates because they can be replaced respectively by `Func<TInput, TOutput>`, `Func<T, bool>` and `Func<T, T, int>`. The only reason they exist is because they were introduced in .NET Framework 2.0 when `Func` delegates didn't exist (they were introduced in .NET Framework 3.5) and are used by some `Array` and `List<T>` methods mentioned in the documentation, hence need to be kept for backward compatibility.

You should limit their usage only for those BCL methods that require them. For all other places and in your own code you should use the newer (and de facto becoming a standard) `Func` delegates.